# can't scroll elements that are under a fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div element with a semi-transparent image, position:fixed, top:0, left:0 and height:100%.
Under that div i have a variable number of elements.

When the number of elements is big enough, the browser scrollbars show but it is not possible to scroll the elements because of the fixed div "over" them.

How could i make the scroll under the fixed div possible?

**The code:**

CSS:

```
.vcBodyShadow{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
     background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.80);
    z-index:1;
}
#VCBody{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.vcElementContainer {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-around;    
    flex-wrap: wrap;      
    height: $height;
    width:$width;
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:lighten($default_blue,44%) !important;    
    min-height:100px;
}
```

".vcBodyShadow" is the fixed div with a shadow image to be shown over the #VCBody.

"#VCBody" is the main container.

".vcElementContainer" is the container of an element, which are inside the #VCBody.

**The Elements will show OVER the shadow and the VCBody with other html code UNDER it.**

And the Jquery to show the shadow over the "#VCBody" with all the elements:

```
$("#VCBody").prepend("<div class='vcBodyShadow'></div>");
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="VCBody">
        <div class="vcElementContainer"></div>
        <div class="vcElementContainer"></div>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your code is ???? ... it's impossible to know where the problem is whitout your code. This works https://jsfiddle.net/fvushnho/

Comment: Are the scrollbars appearing for page elements, or the entire page itself? For example, if the scrollbar is on a `div`, and you have a fixed div over it, you won't be able to focus the div below - and thus, you cannot scroll it. However, a fixed div of 100% height and 100% width should not interrupt *page* scrolling.

Comment: Yes, the scrollbars corresponds to a div container with all the elements. I have added some code for better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea for you, instead of having the image above the element you want to scroll on, how about putting it below them, with the same opacity.

Then also change the opacity of the divs you're scrolling. This will give it the appearance of being underneath.

You would add:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', function(){
    $('#VCBody').prepend('<div class="vcBodyShadow">3</div>');
    $('.vcElementContainer').css('opacity','0.5');
  });
});
```

```css
.vcBodyShadow{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 50px;
}
#VCBody{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.vcElementContainer {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-around;    
    flex-wrap: wrap;      
    height: $height;
    width:$width;
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:yellow;    
    min-height:100px;
    margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="VCBody">
      <div class="vcElementContainer">1</div>
      <div class="vcElementContainer">2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Making some adaptations to my real code it worked great, and the idea solves the problem of the question's title,